# Vue 3 parse string into vue component

Tags: vue.js

I have a string like below:

```
These questions will address {{ selected }}. It is influenced by the following parents: {{ parent }}.
```

and I want to parse {{ }} part as a self-defined **Vue component** instead of pure HTML so I cannot use v-html

For example, I want to replace {{ selected }} as

```
<StateComponent :state="selected"} />
```

Currently, I use Regex to replace {{ }} as a component, but it doesn't work

are there any other ways?

Thank you

Comment: Self defined component?

Comment: Yes, some other Vue template components, instead of HTML tags